# awk can not handle file which row content is more than 2K

Tags: linux, shell, awk, files

I use awk to change a line in a file

```
export textContent="verylongtextmorethan4K"

awk '{ if (NR == 200) print "${textContent}\"; else print $0}' a.txt  > b.txt
```

but if it row text is longer than 2K then it will not work.
I realized it is because of the long text to insert.
How can I solve this problem, to insert 4K long text into a row.

Comment: When you have a large string, what errors (if any) do you get?  I'm guessing you possibly get "argument list too long" due to the size of the environment variable.  Also, you can't use a shell variable in `awk` like how you're doing there. Use `ENVIRON["textContent"]` instead.

Comment: Your command will give `awk: unterminated string` string error due to not closing the quote. Please post the correct command you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Use perl, which is designed to not have such limits.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
    if ($. == 200) {
        print $ENV{'textContent'}, "\n";
    }
    else {
        print;
    }
}
```

Or the short "oneliner" version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) { print ($. == 200) ? ($ENV{'textContent'} . "\n") : $_; }
```

Save the perl script in e.g. `x.pl`, and then run

```
perl x.pl a.txt > b.txt
```

Or first make the script executable:

```
chmod +x x.pl
./x.pl a.txt > b.txt
```

`<>` returns the next line of the input, and at EOF it returns false, so then the loop is terminated.

`$.` is perl's special variable that contains the current input line number.

As perl does not automatically add a newline to whatever `print` is passed as an argument, I have added the `"\n"`. In the first version `print` is passed the enviroment variable's contents and the newline as a list; hence the comma usage. In the second version they are concatenated together as the ternary operator (`?` `:`) expects one value there and not a list.

Perhaps you're not familiar with the ternary operator. It takes this form:

```
condition ? value1 : value2
```

If the condition is true, `value1` is returned, otherwise `value2`. So here, if the line number is 200, then the very long line is returned, otherwise `$_` which is the contentsof the current record (i.e. line).

Comment: Cheekily, the short oneliner version is `perl -lpe '$. == 200 && $_ = $ENV{textContent}' a > b`

Comment: @glennjackman nice one :-)